# Get string between two characters SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, string, split, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I pick *abc1234* from below string?

```
20250-abcdef-abc1234-0123
```

Note* string size varies.

Comment: is it always the next to last "section" in your string?

Comment: Yes, its always next to last in my string listed in question.

Comment: Does the string always have 4 segments? If so `PARSENAME(REPLACE('20250-abcdef-abc1234-0123','-','.'),2)`

Comment: Didn't know PARSENAME was a built-in function in 2008 R2.  Works for me!

Comment: Great use case for PARSENAME. I thought it was 2012. Simple solution @MartinSmith

Comment: I guess we're on 2012 then!  Hooray!

Comment: haha, select @@version will let you know

Comment: We are indeed on 2008R2.  Good to know PARSENAME works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @var varchar(256) = '20250-abcdef-abc1234-0123'

select right(left(@var,len(@var) - charindex('-',reverse(@var))),charindex('-',reverse(left(@var,len(@var) - charindex('-',reverse(@var))))) - 1)
```

**Detailed Version**

```
declare @var varchar(256) = '20250-abcdef-abc1234-0123'
declare @FirstHyphenFromRight int
declare @TrimedToFirstHyphen varchar(256)
declare @SecondHyphenFromRight int
declare @Result varchar(256)

select 
    @FirstHyphenFromRight       =       charindex('-',reverse(@var))
    ,@TrimedToFirstHyphen       =       left(@var,len(@var) - @FirstHyphenFromRight)
    ,@SecondHyphenFromRight     =       charindex('-',reverse(@TrimedToFirstHyphen))
    ,@Result                    =       right(@TrimedToFirstHyphen, @SecondHyphenFromRight - 1)     --minus 1 for the hyphen


select 
    YourString              =   @var
    ,FirstHyphenFromRight   =   @FirstHyphenFromRight
    ,TrimedToFirstHyphen    =   @TrimedToFirstHyphen
    ,SecondHyphenFromRight  =   @SecondHyphenFromRight
    ,Result                 =   @Result
```

Comment: Works for me!  Also, solution Martin Smith mentioned works as well:  PARSENAME(REPLACE('20250-abcdef-abc1234-0123','-','.'),2)

Comment: parsename is great for anything with 4 delimiters like IP addresses, server.db.schema.object, and in your case too.